# How can I mock a higher order function in Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, mocking, jestjs

I would like to a mock a function what looks like:

```
export default (name, onRegComponentSize, debug=false) => event => { 
    if(debug)
        console.warn(`${name} -> ${event.nativeEvent.layout.height}`)

    onRegComponentSize( name, { 
        width: event.nativeEvent.layout.width, 
        height: event.nativeEvent.layout.height
    })
}
```

But got no idea how could I do it. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue to unit test the function itself, and then have the mock basically be a hard-coded version of the actual function. The idea is that once you've unit tested the function you can assume that it is working as intended everywhere else.

Comment: That make sense! It's really pointless to mock this function. I should just unit test the function once, and I can assume its working everywhere.

Comment: I would still argue to mock it, but to have a very simple mock. The reason is that you should never leave non-library imports unmocked so you can limit the functionality that you are testing.

Essentially, have custom mock functions based on the expected result.